# how to handle the undefined array key problem in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, backend

**i was trying to show the result in like a list in a page , but it shows undefined array key problem . i'm still learnign php and new to this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNOPu.png).  how to fix this ? i'm running out of time to submit my uni project , so i don't have much time to search and properly learn full php . **

here is the html code ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="appointment.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>Appointment</h1>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <form action="appointment_process.php" method="post">
        <div class="input-box">
            <label for="select1">Select 1:</label>
            <select id="select1">
                <option value="option1">DHAKA</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            </select>

            <label for="select2">Select 2:</label>
            <select id="select2">
                <option value="option1">heart</option>
                <option value="option2">Option B</option>
                <option value="option3">Option C</option>
            </select>

            <label for="search">Search:</label>
            <input type="text" id="search" class="search-input" placeholder="Type here">
        </div>

        <div class="bottom-boxes">
            <div class="bottom-box">Box 1</div>
            <div class="bottom-box">Box 2</div>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the php code that will work after searching ,

```
<?php
// process_form.php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Retrieve form data and sanitize inputs
    $division = $_POST["select1"];
    $speciality = $_POST["select2"];
    $dname = $_POST["search"];
    
    require_once("partials/_dbconnect.php");

    // Perform appropriate sanitation to prevent SQL injection (e.g., using prepared statements)


    // Prepare SQL statement using prepared statement to prevent SQL injection
    $sql = "SELECT `doctors`.`Name`,
    `specialities`.`Specialities`, `doctors`.`Address` FROM `doctors` LEFT JOIN `specialities` ON`doctors`.`Specialties ID` = `specialities`.`Specialties ID`WHERE `doctors`.`Name` = '$dname' AND
    `specialities`.`Specialities` = '$speciality' AND `doctors`.`Address` = '$division'";
    

    // Prepare and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // $stmt->bind_param("sss", $dname, $speciality, $division);

    // Execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get the result
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // Process the result as needed (e.g., fetch rows, display data, etc.)
    // Example:
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Process each row of the result set
        // For example, echo data or perform operations
        echo "Name: " . $row["Name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Speciality: " . $row["Specialities"] . "<br>";
        echo "Address: " . $row["Address"] . "<br>";
    }

    // Close statement and database connection
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: None of your form elements have a `name` attribute, which is what the browser uses as the key when sending key/value pairs to the server.